# Explain this c# code please

Tags: c#

Can you please explain what's going on in this code (how is it multiplying by 4 as said in comments in code?):

```
 public static int GetNextSize(int i)
  {
    //multiply it by four and make sure it is positive
    return i > 0 ? i << 2 : ~(i << 2) + 1;
  }
```

Is there any better or cleaner way to do this? or is this one the optimum one?

Also, any practical situations where this (or this type of) code will be helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: Besides that this doesn't really looks like PHP code. It simply does: `x > 0` -> return `x * 4`, else when x is negative: return `x * -1 * 4`. Just everything done with bit operators.

Comment: written by some one to cleaver for their own good

Comment: 1 Seems to be C#, not PHP?

Comment: `public static` is not valid in C++.  If you don't even know what language you are using then I would suggest deleting the question

Comment: it's c# then maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The `?` is the ternary operator, effectively a returnable if/else statement

```
if (i>0)
    return i multiplied by four (bitshift to the left two)
else
    return negative i multiplied by four
```

The `~x+1` means two's compliment and add one, effectively making it a negative number. The `x` here happens to be `i<<2`

It looks like some optimized C-like code to me.

For #2, are you referring to the logical OR operator?
 `a || b=c`
Since a is evaluated first, the total expression will be true if `a` is true, so `b=c` is only evaluated is `a` is false. This effectively means `if not a: b=c`

Comment: whats the operator second code operator called?

Comment: `~` is the negate operator if that's what you're referring to

Answer (score 1):

if `i` is positive:

it will shift the bits by two to the left, which is effectively the same as multiplying by 4.

if `i` is not positive (is negative or zero), it will again multiply by 4, then negate all the bits (that's what `~` does) and add 1 (due to [2s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) -- it's necessary for positive numbers).